# why am i getting a NullReferenceException when I try to upload a image?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

hi im new to C# and i am struggling whith this proplem.

i am trying to upload an image and save it to a local folder, but i am geting
a NullReferenceException when i try it..

my controller

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Picture pic)
    {
        Picture newPix = pic;
        if (newPix.File.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(pic.File.FileName);
            //var fileName = pic.File.FileName;
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/images"), fileName);
            pic.File.SaveAs(path);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

my view

```
<div class="row">
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>File:</td>
            <td><input type="file" id="File" /></td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" /></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
}
```

my model

```
{
        public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
    }
```

when i debug, I can see that pic in the controller is NULL,, am i sending the file wrong to the controler from the form?

Comment: What line throws the exception?

Comment: if (newPix.File.ContentLength > 0) this line

Answer (score 2):

Your input file id is "**File**" and the action result is expecting "**pic**"

Update your HTML to

```
<td><input type="file" id="file" name="file" /></td>
```

Update your your Action Method to

```
 public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        Picture newPix = file;
        if (newPix.File.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(pic.File.FileName);
            //var fileName = pic.File.FileName;
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/images"), fileName);
            pic.File.SaveAs(path);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the null reference exception when you tried to read `newPix.File` property. `newPix` is **null** and you are trying to read some property of null.

It is ***null*** because Model binding failed! Model binding happens when your view model property names and your form element names are same. Your form element is missing the `name` attribute. Add it and it should work.

```
<input type="file" name="File" id="File" />
```

Next time when you get an error, put a visual studio break point in your code and inspect the variable values and you will get an idea why it failed.